How can $d\omega=((\cos t+2)\cos s ds-\sin^2sdt)\wedge (\cos t dt )\wedge (-(\cos t+2) \sin s ds-\sin t\cos s dt)=0?$
I have:
$$d\omega=((\cos t+2)\cos s ds-\sin^2sdt)\wedge (\cos t dt )\wedge (-(\cos t+2) \sin s ds-\sin t\cos s dt)$$
which we split up in its components:
$$1: (\cos t+2)\cos s ds\wedge (\cos t dt )\wedge (-(\cos t+2) \sin s ds$$
$$2: (-\sin^2sdt)\wedge (\cos t dt )\wedge(-\sin t\cos s dt))$$
$$3:((\cos t+2)\cos s ds)\wedge (\cos t dt )\wedge -\sin t\cos s dt)$$
and
$$4: (-\sin^2sdt)\wedge (\cos t dt )\wedge(-(\cos t+2) \sin s ds)$$
but the first and the first has a sequence of wedge products as $ds\wedge dt \wedge ds$, how can it be that the rule $ds\wedge ds$ overrules the entire set ?
Thanks

What you mean by "how can it be that the rule $dx\wedge ds$ overrules the entire set"? Is the $dx$ a typo?

Sorry, typo! Thanks for pointing that out. Corrected

Do you know how $ds\wedge dt$ and $dt\wedge ds$ are related?

yes, by the minus sign

Okey, I see what you mean now. We invert that sequence in the first term, and obtain $ds\wedge ds$ there as well. Thanks

That's what I meant, yes. Does that solve your problem?

Yes! Thanks a lot.

No worries. You should write an answer and accept it.

Done, thanks....!

You have 3 factors but only 2 different differentials ($\mathrm{d}s$ and $\mathrm{d}t$). Therefore each term in the expansion will contain at least 2 of the same differential. Such a term vanishes; for example:
$$
\mathrm{d}t \wedge \mathrm{d}s \wedge \mathrm{d}t
= (\mathrm{d}t \wedge \mathrm{d}s) \wedge \mathrm{d}t
= (-\mathrm{d}s \wedge \mathrm{d}t) \wedge \mathrm{d}t
= -\mathrm{d}s \wedge (\mathrm{d}t \wedge \mathrm{d}t)
= -\mathrm{d}s \wedge 0
= 0.
$$
